# onMessageReceived not being called on buld variant release

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made a messaging app and everything works fine but when i run the release version of the app it won't show any notifications sent from users .It shows notifications sent from the server but not from the users . I thought it was  certificate mismatch but i checked everything and there is no problem there .I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and can't seem to get it working

```
  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    try{
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
          sendOreoNotifications(title,message);
        }else {
            sendNotifications(title,message);
        }
    }catch (NullPointerException y){
        y.printStackTrace();
        String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        try{
            if(firebaseUser!=null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
                }else {
                    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
                }


            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Please update flavors config. Are you sure firebase has declare all package name base on flavors of your app

Comment: @CôngHải yes i have updated the flavor config . every other firebase service seems to be working correctly